# Segmentation Fault in using a node struct

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I have this method which is giving me a segmentation fault, I am not able to figure it out. We have to remove the node which matches the name given.

```
typedef struct node
{
int id;
char* name;
struct node* next;
} node;

node* rem_inorder(node** head, char* key_name)
{

node* temp = *head;
int found =0;
while(temp -> next != NULL &&!found)
{

if(temp -> name == key_name){
    printf("works");
    found = -1;}
else {
    temp = temp ->next;}}
if(found == -1)
{return temp;} 
else
{return NULL;}}
```

Comment: no problems I see in the code shown. Your linked list is probably broken from elsewhere before you get to this function. The only dereference you do is `temp->`, so that suggests that `*head` is no good.

Comment: What do you mean by that *head is no good. This is just a temp variable to go through the list. How else should i assign it to the head?

Comment: I'm saying `*head` is probably `NULL` or some garbage value ,, if you are indeed getting a segfault in this function.

Comment: Use a debugger to find the line where the segfault occurs. If you cannot figure out the problem, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function has undefined behavior because the value of the expression `*head` can be equal to `NULL` for an empty list. In this case this expression `temp -> next`  will be invalid.

Also you have to compare strings instead of pointers when you are searching the node.

And according to the description of the assignment you have to remove the found node from the list.

The function can be defined the following way

```
node * rem_inorder( node **head, const char *key_name )
{
    node *target = NULL;

    while ( *head && strcmp( ( *head )->name, key_name ) != 0 )
    {
        head = &( *head )->next;
    }

    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        target = `*head;
        *head = ( *head )->next;
        target->next = NULL;
    }

    return target;
}`
```